# Accessing a list from another class vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have these two classes class FootballAdmin makes use of the import Football from the projects references, what i need to do is in class MainForm is for the updateView method to access the list held by FootballAdmin and display it in the teamSheetListBox, i am unsure how access the list as indicated by ?????

```
Imports Football

Public Class FootballAdmin

  Private fTeam As List(Of FootballTeams)

  Public Sub New()
    fTeam = New List(Of FootballTeams)
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property Teams() As List(Of FootballTeams)
    Get
      Return fTeams
   End Get
  End Property
End Class

Public Class MainForm    
  Private fFootballAdmin As FootballAdmin

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    fFootballAdmin = New FootballAdmin
    updateView()
  End Sub

  Private sub updateView()    
    For each team As String In ????????
      teamSheetListBox.Items.Add(team)
    Next   
  End Sub
End Class
```

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big hint I am going to give you is that team in your loop:

```
For each team As String In ????????
  teamSheetListBox.Items.Add(team)
Next
```

Isn't going to be a String.  It will be the same type: FootballTeam as in your FootballAdmin Class.  Consider what you have access to in your MainForm that can get you to those types.

Comment: Tried as list(of fFootballTeam) in fFootballAdmin.Teams(), that didnt work but would i be going the right way?

Comment: @user445714 Yes, you have it *almost* right.  Hint: team is not a string.

Comment: Yes, definitely closer.  Keep in mind that the general format of that sort of loop is  For VariableName as SingleThing in BiggerGroupOfThings.

Comment: Im not going to get this been sitting for hours trying to work it out going to go with                                                For Each team As List(of fFootballTeam) in fFootballAdmin.Teams()
           teamSheetListBox.Items.Add(team.ToString)
         Next    (and see what marks i get, thanks folks.)